# "mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server" for simple fcgi script that works when run directly

Tags: python, linux, apache, bash, fastcgi

I have the following fcgi script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import subprocess, sys, os
command=["sudo", "-u", "matt", "/home/matt/cgi-bin/peercoin-abe", str(os.getpid())]
subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=sys.stdin).wait()
```

peercoin-abe contains:

```
#! /bin/sh PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 exec python /home/matt/peercoin-explorer/Peercoin-Abe/abe.py \
--config /home/matt/abe-peercoin.conf --static-path static/ --watch-pid="$1" >> /home/matt/abe-peercoin.log
```

But when I try to access it I get the error in the error log:

```
[Fri Aug 22 22:07:08 2014] [warn] [client 149.254.181.200] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Fri Aug 22 22:07:08 2014] [error] [client 149.254.181.200] Premature end of script headers: peercoin-abe.fcgi
```

I have `FcgidIOTimeout 40` and `FcgidBusyTimeout 3600` set. peercoin-abe.fcgi is executable and owned by root. peercoin-abe is executable and owned by matt.

So you would expect output into abe-peercoin.log, but there is none. Running peercoin-abe.fcgi directly causes output to abe-peercoin.log as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Fcgi isn't very explicit about this, but the problem was due to permissions for the web user not being able to execute as matt. Adding this to the sudoers file is necessary:

```
www-data ALL=(matt) NOPASSWD: /home/matt/cgi-bin/peercoin-abe
```